# How to band pass only on positive frequency

Tags: fft, bandpass, hilbert-transform

I've posed the similiar question

I appreciate that the former replier tells me the process is about Hilber transform,but I'm still confused with the positive frequency.

The paper process a cardiac cycles, using a lock-in amplifaction. Chose a region mean pixel value as the time domain signal. After that, it operates fft on the singnal and  band pass only calculating on positive frequency wjich in [0.7~1.5]Hz as in the picture C1 and C2.Therefor, operating ifft on the spectrum gets the reference function.The process is the same in the picture.

[image]

I got 3 questions.

first of all,

Does the 'calculating on positive frequency' mean calculating on the analytic signal? How should I understand the negetive frequency? Should I do any process like fft then cut-off the unwanted frequency or hilber transform then cut-off the real and imag part,or just don't do anything.

Second,
The paper shows the processed spectrum ifft will be a complex number, and the complex number real part and image part would be orthogonal.Does Hilbert transform satisfy the required?

```
for i = 1:1024
   filename = ['image' num2str(i) '.tiff'];
   img(:,:,i)= imread(filename);  %1024 points
   rawdata(i) = mean2(img(110:140,110:140,i))  % image ROI pixel mean as time signal
end
nfft=1024/2;
[row,column]=size(img(:,:,1));
ldf=samplerate/(nfft-1);          % calculate band pass location
Freq_range=[0.7 1.5];
R1 = round(Freq_range(1)/ldf);
R2 = round(Freq_range(2)/ldf);
Y=fft(rawdata);
Y(1:R1)=0;                       % band pass 
Y(R2:nfft+1)=0;
[m,p]=max(Y(1:nfft+1));          % the dominate frequency
Rcfeq_MXfeq=p*ldf;
BP_data=ifft(Y);                 % ifft signal is a complex number

%% lock in amplification
corrematrix = zeros(row,column);
for i = 1: length(rawdata)
    corrematrix = corrematrix +raw_img(:,:,i)*BP_data(i);
end

t = [0:1023]/samplerate; % 時間向量
for j = 1 : length(rawdata)
        H = real(corrematrix)*cos(2*pi*Rcfeq_MXfeq*t(j))+imag(corrematrix)*sin(2*pi*Rcfeq_MXfeq*t(j));
```

Last,
How to implement the band pass filter to my signal would be mach the paper result , my code is like below.

The former replier had told me do fft on the analytic signal wolud be only positive component.Does it mean I just doing band pass on the analytic signal and the ifft would be the result.

````
```samplerate=30;      
for i = 1:1024
   filename = ['image' num2str(i) '.tiff'];
   img(:,:,i)= imread(filename);  %1024 points
   rawdata(i) = mean2(img(110:140,110:140,i))  % image ROI pixel mean as time signal
end
nfft=1024/2;
[row,column]=size(img(:,:,1));
ldf=samplerate/(nfft-1);          % calculate band pass location
Freq_range=[0.7 1.5];
R1 = round(Freq_range(1)/ldf);
R2 = round(Freq_range(2)/ldf);
rawdata_a=hilbert(rawdata)       % hilbert transform
Y=fft(rawdata_a);
Y(1:R1)=0;                       % band pass 
Y(R2:nfft+1)=0;
[m,p]=max(Y(1:nfft+1));          % the dominate frequency
Rcfeq_MXfeq=p*ldf;
BP_data=ifft(Y);                 % ifft signal is a complex number
````

The artical is Photoplethysmographic imaging of high spatial resolution

DOI is 10.1364/BOE.2.000996

Comment: I’m sorry, but rather than asking the same question twice, please *edit* your previous question! [fast fourier transform band pass filter only on positive frequency](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/89272/fast-fourier-transform-band-pass-filter-only-on-positive-frequency)

Comment: Since your question seems to revolve around not understanding the Hilbert transform I suggest that rather than asking your whole question again, you first _search the web_ for information on why signal processing folks talk about positive and negative frequencies (there's plenty of answers here on Stack Exchange), then why the Hilbert transform is used, ditto.